# Extraction of connection string from web config using web service

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, wordpress, sql-server-2008

I have this tricky scenario and want so advice to you. My client have a website built in WordPress and a web application that was built in .Net 3.5 now they want me to integrate this too site by querying some information from the database that .Net is using and display the output on the said website.

Communication between the two site is complete and working fine using some DLL for PHP to integrate to MSSQL now the problem arises here, my don't want to expose he connection string on the website built on WordPress for security reason. Without this, I can't connect to the database and made some query so I propose some bright idea, using a web service to extract connection string from the web config of ASP.Net web application. Consuming of web service to PHP is working fine but the last issue is that the web service is expose in public. what I mean once the site launch online, the said web service is open to public and anyone can see thru the web config that my boss want to keep in secret (hehehe).

I'm already confuse on how to make the web service to be more secure. Below are some specification of the two websites.

WordPress Site

- PHP based
- Mysql
- installed with php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll and php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
- nusoap (use to consume ASP.Net webservice)
- Mysql for database using by WordPress

.Net Site

- web service to extract connection string from web config
- web reference added
- MSSQL for database

Please let me know if you need more information regarding my problem.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to setup a web service for this. Just store the connection string in a php file outside of your web servers root directory (probably public_html) and then include that file within you plugin. You should hard-code the path, so that people with access to the setting can't use that functionality to spy on other files. Also make sure the web server service account has read access to that file.

That is a pretty safe setup as the file can't be directly accessed through the web.